# Align UISlider thumb image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uislider

I've customized my `UISlider` but my thumb image looks strange, I mean it's position not aligned by center:

[image]

But should be like this:

[image]

And here is code:

```
UIImage *leftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueTrack.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:3 topCapHeight:0];
UIImage *rightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteTrack.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:3 topCapHeight:0];
[slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMinimumTrackImage:leftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:rightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Your stretch image is not exactly as high as UISlider's internal implementation requires it to be. Try making it less high.

Comment: Well - use GIMP, Photoshop, Paint.net... :)

Comment: Oh, you mean do it not programmaticaly:) Ok, I'll try

Comment: Unfortunately this not helped. What sizes these 3 images should be?

Comment: Your thumb should be 25x25 I believe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

First one is to use

```
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
```

and / or

```
- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value;
```

methods of `UISlider` when subclassing to lay out thumb the way you want

---

Second way is to adjust your artwork:

[image]